# Проставление onClick на ссылки при загрузке страницы с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

Есть задача, проставить Event для некоторых ссылок. Решил закрыть задачу с помощью JS. Вот что у меня получилось. Осталось распарсить ссылку и передать название файла (первый if) или SKU (второй if) в Event. При этом, второй if в таком исполнении работает.

```
    for (let elem of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) {
        if (elem.matches('a[href$="pdf"]')) {
            elem.setAttribute("onclick", "amplitude.getInstance().logEvent('download_file', { type: 'pdf', reference: '%file_name%'} );");
        }
        if (elem.matches('a[href$="https://site.com/shop/"]')) {
            elem.setAttribute("onclick", "amplitude.getInstance().logEvent('shop_click', { type: 'link', reference: '%SKU%'} );");
        }
    }
```

Подскажите, как реализовать передачу параметра в Event.

Comment: «проставить Event», «передать название файла в Event» =__= что бы это значило... `reference: '" + elem.href + "'} ` ? Еще бы второй `if` заменить на `else if` - чтобы выполнялся всегда только один.

Answer (score 1):

Для парсинга нужных значений можно воспользоваться [регулярными выражениями](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

К сожалению, вы не уточнили откуда именно берётся SKU, поэтому пример только для первого if

```
for (let elem of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) {
    if (elem.matches('a[href$="pdf"]')) {
        
        // берём последнюю часть url
        // Пример работы регулярного выражения: https://regex101.com/r/dAK6Fa/1
        let filename = elem.href.match(/.*(\/|^)(.+?\.pdf)/)[2];

        // обращаю внимание на смену кавычек " -> `
        elem.setAttribute("onclick", `amplitude.getInstance().logEvent('download_file', { type: 'pdf', reference: '${filename}'} );`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, при манипуляциях с кодом за комментировый кусок кода потерял.

Comment: https://site.com/shop/SKU структура ссылки всегда одинаковая, только SKU меняется

Comment: В таком случае, выражение не будет сильно отличаться [regex101.com/r/dAK6Fa/2](https://regex101.com/r/dAK6Fa/2). Так же хочу обратить внимание на то, что в таком случае, селектор для проверки (`elem.matches('a[href$="https://site.com/shop/"]')`) написан неправильно и вероятно подразумевалось `a[href^="..."]`